# Binding Composite Object to Tree View WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview, composite

I have an object that follows Composite design pattern. I would like to show this object in a WPF using tree view but I have trouble binding the data correctly. I have two classes: Leaf, simple class that doesnt have any children, and Box, compound class that has children elements which could be both of Leaf class of Box class. I also have a common interface called ITree

Interface

```
public interface ITree
{
  string Name { get; }
  string Property1 { get; }
  string Property2 { get; } 
}
```

Simple class

```
public class Leaf : ITree
{
  string ITree.Name { get { return _name; } }
  string ITree.Property1 { get { return property1; } }
  string ITree.Property2 { get { return property2; } }
}
```

Compound class

```
public class Box : ITree
{
  string ITree.Name { get { return _name; } }
  string ITree.Property1 { get { return property1; } }
  string ITree.Property2 { get { return property2; } }
  List<ITree> Children = new List<ITree>();
}
```

xaml.cs

```
List<ITree> ListToBind = new List<ITree>();
ITree finalObject = PopulateCompositeObjeectWithData();
ListToBind.Add(finalObject);
```

xaml

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path= ListToBind}">
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The tree view I am trying to achieve:

```
Box - Name
  |-Leaf - Name
  |-Leaf - Name
  |-Box - Name
  |  |-Leaf - Name
  |  |-Leaf - Name
```

Any suggestion or code samples would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Children` must be *public property* for you to be able to bind to it:

```
public class Box : ITree
{
    string ITree.Name { get { return _name; } }
    string ITree.Property1 { get { return property1; } }
    string ITree.Property2 { get { return property2; } }
    public List<ITree> Children { get; } = new List<ITree>();
}
```

Second, you should bind to explicit implemented interface members using parentheses like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path= ListToBind}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding (local:ITree.Name)}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!